# ERC20 token transfer to another address

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am currently learning solidity and I have created a smart contract that can handle transfer of ERC-20 token from one address to another. But I have encountered a problem wherein upon executing createTransaction function the token is being transferred to the contract address instead of the wallet address.

Please see code below

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";

contract TransactionContract {
    enum TransactionType {
        payment,
        donation
    }
    struct Transaction {
        string description;
        TransactionType transaction_type;
        IERC20 token;
        uint256 exchange_rate;
        uint256 amount;
        uint256 converted_amount;
        string remarks;
    }

    string public display_name;
    address public wallet_address;
    string[] public transaction_list;
    mapping(string => Transaction) public transactions;

    function initializeProfile(string memory displayName) public {
        display_name = displayName;
        wallet_address = msg.sender;
    }

    function createTransaction(string memory transactionID, Transaction memory transactionDetails) payable public {
        require(msg.value >= transactionDetails.converted_amount);
        transactionDetails.token.transfer(payable(wallet_address), transactionDetails.converted_amount);
        transactions[transactionID] = transactionDetails;
        transaction_list.push(transactionID);
    }

}
```

Here is a sample transaction hash upon execution https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x1413bdbe54222326a1faa805ad51b6a1a69afdd001c3545e4da2b59864e0f35d

Comment: This snippet attempts to transfer the token **from** the contract address **to** the `wallet_address` - but your question states that it's transferring **to** the contract address... Can you check if you really meant **to** the contract, and if yes, please provide more context and repro steps to your issue? Possibly the `wallet_address` is incorrectly set?

Comment: @PetrHejda yes as far as my research the snippet would transfer it to the wallet address but upon executing the function the token is being transferred to the contract address. added the full contract code and sample transaction details for more clarity thank you so much

Comment: In the transfer function, you are getting parameter "string memory transactionID, Transaction memory transactionDetails", can you please specify exactly where is your wallet address. Further more, What I would do is 1- take the wallet address in transfer() parameter 2- I would hardcode the address like "address public wallet_address = 0x...;"